# Vertical Line Artifacts in Blender Cycles 2.83

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

just got Blender 2.83 today and noticed these weird artifact lines in my cycles renders. It happens in the render viewport, and in final renders. It only happens when I use GPU acceleration, CPU is fine. I have a Sapphire RX 580. They seem to fade if I ramp up the render passes, suggesting that they're a type of noise. I made a test scene with three point lights in a volume, 256 passes and no denoising. You can really see it just to the right of the red light and the top edge. Is this a known issue?

[image: Scene with three point lights]

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug. Is it possible you could upload your file so we can try on other hardware?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/b4c7f70570da429dbc47b19a987c25e8

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, kinda stupid. Just had to update my graphics drivers.