# Burn marks on the render and strange lines, shadow composite not working

Tags: rendering

Can someone help me? i have been doing these donuts for today, my fisrt problem was the shadows where very grainy but i fixed it with https://gyazo.com/b9d12de8a32b27197d1d887c1615a83b
compositing and now when i made some sprinklers on the donuts it just became like this
https://gyazo.com/8c9deed39046848f6f37878936041898
 and i have no idea on how to fix it

Comment: Not sure from the photo, but it looks like you have way overblown values for the specular reflections, causing a massive, noisy bloom. Only thing I can think of from your setup is to uncheck the HDR box on the denoise node - that should bring the whites (and hopefully the brightness) back to a range between 0 and 1.

Comment: ddeactivating the HDR fixed the strange lights but the lines are still there

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about that. Never seen it before myself. One thing I found while seraching though, updating graphics drivers worked for one user. Link is here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181194/vertical-line-artifacts-in-blender-cycles-2-83